# How do I get only the new lines from a string (an EC2 box' console output) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rake

I am writing a Rake task that boots an EC2 instance and runs some commands on it.

AWS' Ruby SDK has:

`instance.console_output`, which returns a `String` of the full output (from the moment the machine booted until present).

What I really want is the "diff" between the last output and the current, so that I can just print the new lines to my local console.

I *feel* like there should be a tool for this somewhere in a Gem or Ruby library, but searching on Google has yielded nothing.

Any help, or am I stuck doing:

```
total = output.lines.length
new_lines = total - last
puts output.lines[-1..new_lines].to_a.join
last = total
```

in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Check out...

- [differ](https://github.com/pvande/differ)
- [diffy](https://github.com/samg/diffy)
- [diff-lcs](http://rubygems.org/gems/diff-lcs)

These are just a few that I've come across.  There are many others.